# Paste Formatted HTML into Arduino Sketch

Tags: html, json, arduino, webserver, esp8266

I'm writing a Web Server with an ESP8266 and is built with an Arduino sketch. The Web Server works fine, but for each line of HTML I need to write client.print("string")

I built a more well formatted app outside of the Arduino sketch and I'm looking for a way to easily copy and paste HTML into the sketch when the HTML code could potentially be very long.

Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>This HTML written in an Arduino Sketch<h1>
<div>
<table2 style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <td><button class="editbtn">Preset 1</button></td>
  <td><button class="editbtn">Preset 2</button></td>
  <td><button class="editbtn">Preset 3</button></td>
  <td><button class="editbtn">Preset 4</button></td>
  <td><button class="editbtn">Preset 5</button></td>
 </tr>
</div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I copy and paste this into an Arduino Sketch without having to use copy and paste every line? Ideally I'd like the HTML part of the sketch to look similar to the formatting above.

I'm trying to find a way around doing what is shown below to improve any debugging I might need to later in a later and more complicated app.

```
client.print(<!DOCTYPE html>)
client.print(<html>)
client.print(<body>)
client.print(<h1>This HTML written in an Arduino Sketch<h1>)
client.print(<div>)
........etc.......
```

Any help or work around would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to do things like that, I use Microsoft’s Visual Studio editor (although any text editor that supports advanced search and replace functionality would work). You can download the free version of this editor from Microsoft (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx).

Open or paste your HTML into a new text file in Visual Studio (or editor of your choice) and perform a Find and Replace operation (e.g. CTRL-SHIFT-H). Do the following on the “Find and Replace” dialog:

- Use the following for the “Find what:” field:

`^(?<line>[^\r\n]*)\r?\n`

- Use the following for the “Replace with:” field:

`client.print("${line}");\n`

- Select “Current Document” option for the “Look in:” field.
- Check the “Use Regular Expressions” checkbox.
- Click the “Replace All” button.
- Copy the results to your Arduino sketch file.

Before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>This HTML written in an Arduino Sketch<h1>
<div>
```

After:

```
client.print("<!DOCTYPE html>");
client.print("<html>");
client.print("<body>");
client.print("<h1>This HTML written in an Arduino Sketch<h1>");
client.print("<div>");
client.print("");
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. Very Thorough. I will try this!